# Does bearer token needs to be generated in a specific way

Tags: authentication, jwt, token, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to handle an Account Linking for Alexa Skill but in the process of redirecting the user to the `redirect_uri` provided by Alexa Service with the token like this :

```
https://layla.amazon.com/spa/skill/account-linking-status.html?vendorId=MXKMU5XOML3R4&state=stringofState&access_token=stringGeneratedwithJWS&token_type=Bearer
```

I'm getting this error from Alexa Service :

[image]

Which means : **"It seems that *access_token* parameter is not in the request"**

So my question is, do i need to generate my token in a specific way or should every token be accepted and the problem is from another place ?

Comment: This is by far the best article written as far as step by step account linking with amazon. I hope it is helpful for you. https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx3CX1ETRZZ2NPC/Alexa-Account-Linking-5-Steps-to-Seamlessly-Link-Your-Alexa-Skill-with-Login-wit

Comment: The problem is i can't use Amazon to log on and generate the token because i have to handle myself the credentials. But i really don't understand why my tokens are not working.